# How can I format the final message to have the final grade?

Tags: python

How can I convert the final message function with `gradePercent` to get the **65.9** and `letterGrade` to get a **C** and have it display the actual message as an example:

"If things keep going the way they are, you should get a **65.9%** in the course, which is a **C**."

`print("If things keep going the way they are, you should get a " earnedPercent "in the course, which is a " + earnedGrade")`

I also would like to know a way how to change both final percentages from 100% - 0% and letters from A - F automatically if you put in a different input as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Your question is unclear: your description contains only one final percentage, so we don't know how you plan to convert "both", nor what you want to convert them *to*.  Your post appears to be your entire program, rather than the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the posting guildeline.

Comment: The program doesn't run as posted: it has indentation errors, and it hangs waiting for input.  Please conform to the posting guidelines from the intro tour.

Comment: @Prune, I fixed it but the comments for both gradePercent and letterGrade is there in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to the end to get a proper message format based on the percentage:

```
gradePercent=76.5
score=int(gradePercent)
if score > 90:
    letterGrade= "A"
elif 80 <= score < 90:
    letterGrade= "B"
elif 70 <= score < 80:
    letterGrade= "B"
elif 60 <= score < 70:
    letterGrade= "C"
elif 50 <= score < 60:
    letterGrade= "D"
else:
    letterGrade= "F"


#python2
message='If things keep going the way they are, you should get a {:.00f}% in the course, which is a {:s}.'.format(gradePercent, letterGrade)


#python3
#message=f'If things keep going the way they are, you should get a {gradePercent:.00f}% in the course, which is a {letterGrade}.'

print(message)
```

Comment: I tried to run this code to test it out, however it said there was a error. Do you mind clarifying this more?

Comment: Try it now, i updated it, i forgot to add the gradePercent

Comment: I did and I got `{gradePercent:.00f}%` and `{letterGrade}` as the result instead of the actual percentage and letter.

Comment: you have to use python3 for 'f.  Try running python3 from the command line instead. If not wait a few minutes, i'll update it with a python2 version of the print command

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize I wasn't on Python3. I just tried it. It worked, thank you very much!